# Is there a place where people can share (or buy) ready made neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, resource-request

Is there a place where people can share (or buy) ready made neural networks instead of creating them themselves? Something like a Wikipedia for DNNs?

Comment: I suppose you could count kaggle as one place. Post a competition with a prize pool, and just take the model that performs best.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a specific web for sell or share neural network models, but actually you can easily find other people models in Github! Just search it! For example, this is a random repo I've found for [Cat Classification](https://github.com/batogov/cat-breeds-classifier).

But.. the problem is everyone have different problems. So you can't easily use other people neural network models and then use it for your problem. That's why there's a "trick" called [transfer learning or fine tuning](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5347-how-transferable-are-features-in-deep-neural-networks). That method show you how to train other people models (it's called: pre-trained models) from different problems for your specific problem.

Tensorflow and PyTorch provide a lot of pre-trained model for common problems:

- [Pytorch Image Classification Pre-Trained models](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/models.html)
- [Tensorflow Object Detection Model Zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/r1.12.0/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md)
- [PyTorch Detectron Model Zoo](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/master/MODEL_ZOO.md)

You can also find other pre-trained models in Github! This is [an official PyTorch tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/finetuning_torchvision_models_tutorial.html#) how to use that pre-trained model to your specific case.

**UPDATE**

You can also check [HuggingFace Models Hub](https://huggingface.co/models) it's like a repository for machine learning model (most of them are transformer-based and for NLP). It's well organized, you can sort by your specific task or library